# Vue - how to create unique key with v-for="item in 3"

Tags: vue.js, key

I have such a template in Vue:

```
    <AutoTaskBlock  ref="block" v-for="(block, index) in 2" key="index" class="block"></autoTaskBlock>
    <AutoTaskCircle ref="block" v-for="(circle, index) in 3" key="index" class="circle"></autoTaskCircle>
```

So i do have two lists of components which are created "from air" - i do not use any array to create it from it - in this helps me ability to use "v-for="anything in (int)". However vue warns me that any list made by v-for needs unique key. I wanted to use index, but it is duplicated and this gives me no warning but error. 
My next attempt was to use some random value computed in

> computed: {  rand() { return Math.random()*100 } }

but using it like this:

```
    <AutoTaskBlock  ref="block" v-for="(block, index) in 2" key="rand" class="block"></autoTaskBlock>
    <AutoTaskCircle ref="block" v-for="(circle, index) in 3" key="rand" class="circle"></autoTaskCircle>
```

..results the same error. After checking - computed "rand" is randomized only when created, not later so each is the same. Next attempt was to create method of rand like this:

> methods: {   rand: function() { return Math.random()*100 } }

But same - duplicate key error appears. Is there a way to use two lists like this and give them a unique key?

thanks,
Kalreg:

PS: same ref in both components is as i desired, so no error here.

Comment: Surely @psidom had good idea but real problem was lack of colon before key. Adding it solved a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One options is to prefix `index` with a unique word for each list you are creating to deduplicate; For your case something like `'block' + index` and `'circle' + index`:

```
<AutoTaskBlock  ref="block" v-for="(block, index) in 2" :key="'block' + index" class="block"></autoTaskBlock>
<AutoTaskCircle ref="block" v-for="(circle, index) in 3" :key="'circle' + index" class="circle"></autoTaskCircle>
```

Comment: Keys don't need to be unique across for loops, so there is no need for a prefix. Instead, as @Kalreg noticed, the colon was missing.